# How to remove the beginning/ending spaces in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, html, ionic2, whitespace

Is there possible/easy solution to remove spaces from the beginning/ending of the input field

For example, let assume * is space and user entered "***Word*", so how can I check and save the word without the spaces ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javaScript you can do this.

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

try to use `trim`

Hope this helps.